# how to display checkboxes in templates depending on loaded enties of a model

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model named Publication that has several fields among them a field called tags, and I'm using for it `django-taggit`.
I have a page that I display in it some entries of Publication model, I want to display (as checkboxes) on sidebar tags that used only in these entries.
This is a portion of my code:

```
class TagsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ['tags']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TagsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            entries = Tag.objects.all()
            self.fields['tags'].queryset = entries
```